# How to instantiate viewmodel in recycler view adapter class

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to create play store like layout in which I am fetch data in recycler view adapter class using view model but I am getting error at the time of viewmodel instantiation in adapter class.

Here is the JSON response:

```
{
"status": "200",
"message": "Success",
"result": [
    {
        "_id": "60f516fa846e059e2f19c50c",
        "category": "Shirts",
        "sku": [
            {
                "name": "Oxford shirt",
                "brand": "John players",
                "price": "25",
                "color": "Blue",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi1.jpg?alt=media&token=64779194-e3b5-484f-a610-c9a20648b64c"
            },
            {
                "name": "Buttoned down",
                "brand": "Gap originals",
                "price": "45",
                "color": "Pink",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi2.jpg?alt=media&token=0b207b90-f1bc-4771-b877-809648e6bdc1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Collared",
                "brand": "Arrow",
                "price": "30",
                "color": "White",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi3.jpg?alt=media&token=2c1bb3f8-e739-4f09-acbc-aa11fed795e3"
            },
            {
                "name": "Printed",
                "brand": "John players",
                "price": "30",
                "color": "Olive green",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi4.jpg?alt=media&token=666f94bf-4769-44fe-a909-3c81ca9262f7"
            },
            {
                "name": "Hoodie",
                "brand": "Levis",
                "price": "44",
                "color": "Yellow",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/shi5.jpg?alt=media&token=65fccef4-a882-4278-b5df-f00eb2785bf1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f51c37846e059e2f19c50f",
        "category": "Shoes",
        "sku": [
            {
                "name": "Sneakers",
                "brand": "Puma",
                "price": "35",
                "color": "Black and white",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho1.jpg?alt=media&token=d078988d-9e85-4313-bb4a-c9d46e09f0b9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Running shoe",
                "brand": "Nike",
                "price": "99",
                "color": "Multicolor",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho2.jpg?alt=media&token=ed2e7387-3cf6-44df-9f7d-69843eb0bcdf"
            },
            {
                "name": "Yezzy",
                "brand": "Adidas",
                "price": "349",
                "color": "Gray",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho3.jpg?alt=media&token=2c37ef76-37bb-4bdd-b36c-dea32857291f"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sneakers",
                "brand": "Puma",
                "price": "79",
                "color": "Black",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho4.jpg?alt=media&token=4acd763e-8b93-47cd-ba45-92f34af4cf83"
            },
            {
                "name": "Joyride running",
                "brand": "Nike",
                "price": "80",
                "color": "White",
                "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koovs-1ff31.appspot.com/o/sho5.jpg?alt=media&token=e3780dcc-52cb-49d5-9791-e0a44870716c"
            }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is my code:

This is parent recycler view row that contains category title and horizontal recycler view.

**parent_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="12dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/catTitle"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#345"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/childRecycler"
    android:layout_below="@+id/catTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is horizontal recycler view row that contains images related to the category title.

**child_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CatImgAdapter.kt**

```
class CatImgAdapter(private val context: Context,private val imgList:List<Sku>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CatImgAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    return ViewHolder(ChildRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val model = imgList[position]
    Glide.with(context).load(model.img).into(holder.binding.img)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return imgList.size
}

data class ViewHolder(val binding:ChildRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

**CategoryAdapter.kt**

```
class CategoryAdapter(private val context: Context,private val categories:List<Result>): 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
   return ViewHolder(ParentRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val model = categories[position]
    holder.binding.catTitle.text = model.category

    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(context).get(CatImagesViewModel::class.java)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return categories.size
}

class ViewHolder(val binding:ParentRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

I am getting error in `val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(context).get(CatImagesViewModel::class.java)` this line.

**CatImageViewModel.kt**

```
class CatImagesViewModel: ViewModel() {

private var catImageList:MutableLiveData<List<Sku>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getCatImg(): LiveData<List<Sku>>{

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient().create(ApiService::class.java)
        val response = retrofit.getCatImg()

        if(response.isSuccessful){

            val cnt = response.body()!!.result.size

            for(i in 0 until cnt){
                catImageList.postValue(response.body()!!.result[i].sku)
            }
        }
    }

    return catImageList
  }
}
```

Someone let me know how can I instantiate above viewmodel in adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do here, but you should not be do instantiation of ViewModel in a RecyclerView Adapter anyway.

The ViewModel should be there in the Fragment or Activity which hosts the recycler view that you are using because it is tied to the lifecycle of that particular activity or Fragment.

So do the instantiation there and hit the API there and just pass on the data to RecyclerView because that is all it needs. The data. It should not have anything to do with the ViewModel or API calls.

Comment: I am trying to create nested recycler view like play store so I have `Title` and horizontal `RecyclerView` as a row item of parent recyclerview. So in the adapter of parent recycler view I am trying to instantiate view model to fetch data for horizontal recycler view.

Comment: I get the idea, but that is still wrong. The structure then should be you should be submitting a list of different data to your parent recyclerView and from there on assign to the horizontal ones.

Comment: I have updated my post plz let me now how can I correct it.